# Why is Levenberg-Marquardt only used with least squares problem?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I've noticed the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm is only used with least squares problem and I didn't find any library in R or Python  which allow to minimise the absolute values of the residual *(and not the square of the residual)*

1. Is there any reason of that ?
2. Does it make sense to apply `sqrt(abs(residual))` on the residual before it's been squared if we want to use this algorithm with Least Absolute Deviation instead of Least Squares Deviation ?

Comment: Is it because sqrt(abs(x)) is not differentiable when x=0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is based on a Second Order Approximation of the Squared Residual Function.

Hence it requires "Squared Residual Function".
The method will fit any model you can make which has the same form.